# Why does the different speed of light in different media cause refraction?

Tags: speed-of-light, refraction

Why doesn't light simply go more slowly without bending? Is there a macro phenomenon, say a stream of bullets, that will also bend as it changes from one medium to another or is light somehow unique?

Comment: Matching fields at the boundary…

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a macro phenomenon, say a stream of bullets, that will also bend as it changes from one medium to another or is light somehow unique?

If you drive a car off of a smooth hard road onto a soft rough surface the car’s path will also bend like light refracting, unless you deliberately counter-steer.

Comment: why bring up steering? why not just a projectile?

Comment: I used a car because many people have experience driving cars and have experienced this phenomenon. I mention steering because those same people have experience steering and understand how to counter-steer in this situation. I don’t know if projectiles do this.

Comment: so maybe wheels cause this and that does not sound analogous to light.

Comment: Sure. Light isn’t bullets either. No massive object will have the same mechanism as a massless field. You asked if light was unique in this behavior. It is not. An unsteered car will “refract” as it goes from a fast medium to a slow one

Answer (score 0):

The bending of the light rays occurs because light is a wave.
This refraction is not unique to light waves.
It occurs with all kinds of waves (for example also with sound waves),
as soon as the speed of the waves (and hence the wavelength)
changes from one medium to another.

When waves pass from one medium to another the wave fronts of course
remain continuous (i.e. without gaps at the boundary)
in spite of the changing speed and wavelength.
The wavefronts can stay continuous at the boundary
only by bending their their direction.

[image]
(screenshot of animated image at [ISVR - Rfraction, Snells Law](https://resource.isvr.soton.ac.uk/spcg/tutorial/tutorial/Tutorial_files/Web-inter-refrac.htm))